# Suffix Array construction in nlogn time

Tags: string, algorithm, c++11, suffix-array

I am trying to understand the working of suffix array from this link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-2-a-nlognlogn-algorithm/. In this link I have understood the code and the procedure to first sort by 2 characters and then 4 characters and 8 characters and so on.
What I didn't get is - that the limit is taken as 2*n. WHy is that ? If the length of the string is 6 only 1 iteration would be enough. The relevant code snippet is below. ALso the same link also provide another Standford universtiy paper for suffix array that totally bounced over my head. The relevant link of the paper is - https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/suffix-array.pdf. In this paper under section suffix array (Page 5) if some one can explain in more intuitive way the example and the code in C++ written in that paper. It would be really helpful.

```
for (int k = 4; k < 2*n; k = k*2) 
    { 
        // Assigning rank and index values to first suffix 
        int rank = 0; 
        int prev_rank = suffixes[0].rank[0]; 
        suffixes[0].rank[0] = rank; 
        ind[suffixes[0].index] = 0; 

        // Assigning rank to suffixes 
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            // If first rank and next ranks are same as that of previous 
            // suffix in array, assign the same new rank to this suffix 
            if (suffixes[i].rank[0] == prev_rank && 
                    suffixes[i].rank[1] == suffixes[i-1].rank[1]) 
            { 
                prev_rank = suffixes[i].rank[0]; 
                suffixes[i].rank[0] = rank; 
            } 
            else // Otherwise increment rank and assign 
            { 
                prev_rank = suffixes[i].rank[0]; 
                suffixes[i].rank[0] = ++rank; 
            } 
            ind[suffixes[i].index] = i; 
        } 

        // Assign next rank to every suffix 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            int nextindex = suffixes[i].index + k/2; 
            suffixes[i].rank[1] = (nextindex < n)? 
                                  suffixes[ind[nextindex]].rank[0]: -1; 
        } 

        // Sort the suffixes according to first k characters 
        sort(suffixes, suffixes+n, cmp); 
    } 

    // Store indexes of all sorted suffixes in the suffix array 
    int *suffixArr = new int[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        suffixArr[i] = suffixes[i].index; 

    // Return the suffix array 
    return  suffixArr; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its always good if you start with a small example:

let we choose the 'ABABAC'.

First round:

In the first round the we assigned the following ranks: (0,1,0,1,0,2) because this is the order of the 1 length substrings.

Second round:

The second round we sort neighboors from the first round:
((0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(2,-1)) // the -1 means there are no characters

if you sort this lexicographically you get this order (0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,-1). so you assing :

- (0,1) -> 0 (AB)
- (0,2) -> 1 (AC)
- (1,0) -> 2 (BA)
- (2,-1) -> 3 (C)

So this round ends with this order: (0,2,0,2,1,3)

Third round: you choose pairs, but not the neighboors, because every step you should multiply the distance by 2. So this round you setup the pairs the i-th index and (i+2)-th index of the previous round final order.

((0,0),(2,2),(0,1),(2,3),(1,-1),(3,-1)). If you sort this you get the following ranks:

- (0,0) -> 0 (ABAB)
- (0,1) -> 1 (ABAC)
- (1,-1) -> 2 (AC)
- (2, 2) -> 3 (BABA)
- (2,3) -> 4  (BAC)
- (3,-1) -> 5 (C)

(0,3,1,4,2,5) and this is the final order of the suffixes, because now every position is different, you don't need another step, but in the next step we would use the (i-th, (i+4)-th) pairs.

I think this algorithm coomplexity its O(nlog^2n) because we using sorting log n times. I think the suffix tree can solve this kind of problems with O log n complexity, but its much harder to implement.

Your question:

"that the limit is taken as 2*n. WHy is that ? If the length of the string is 6 only 1"

Its not enough always. E.g if the string is 'AAAAAB', than after the first iteration you would calculate the order of the first 4 characters, from every position, so the first and the second position is still the same because its 'AAAA', so you need one more iteration to can strictly order those.

Comment: Thanks Istvan for your intuitive response. It makes more sense now.